# sendmail only relaying messages bound for one specific domain

Tags: sendmail

I was wondering if you could please help me with what could be a simple problem but i cant seem to figure it out.

We have a few centos servers running sendmail (all internal servers on the local lan)- with a very simplistic sendmail configuration (all default) except for a relay everything to our exchange server option i.e DSourexchangeserver
Now what i want to do is have these centos servers sendmail configurations ONLY relay emails destined for our companys domain i.e me@mycompaniesdomain.com
I do not want mail relayed to anywhere else.
Is there anyway to get sendmail to check mails being passed to it and only relay ones on to our exchange server that meet the requirement of being destined for our companies domain and stop everything else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I set it up :

1 sendmail server that all email from nix machines goes to and gets relayed to the exchange server depending on where the email is bound for.

All clients sendmail configs have a DS option for the server above.

On the 1 sendmail server (that all your sendmail configs will point to for the DS option that will act as the filter do the following :

1. Make sure in `sendmail.mc` under `/etc/mail` it has the : `Feature('mailertable', 'hash -o /etc/mailertable.db' dnl` line in it.
2. Comment out the line that says ``` DAEMON_OPTIONS(``Port=smtp,Addr=127.0.0.1, Name=MTA')dnl ``` (so that it can relay for all machines - obviously this wouldn't be a good idea for a machine that has a public IP - but that's not what I'm doing here)
3. `vi mailertable` and put in the following line : `yourdomain.com ESMTP:[yourexchangeserverip]`
4. Create a file under `/etc/mail` called `relay-domains` and put in the following line : `yourdomain.com`
5. Run `m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf`
6. Run `makemap hash /etc/mail/mailertabledb < /etc/mail/mailertable`
7. start or restart the sendmail daemon , `/etc/init.d/sendmail restart`

Then on all the machines you want to have email filter for just go into the sendmail.cf and set the DS option to the ip or hostname of your server above. Then restart sendmail.

Answer (score 2):

See:
http://www.sendmail.org/tips/relaying

> The simplest approach is to list the domains you are willing to relay
>   in the file /etc/mail/relay-domains. Anything listed in this file will
>   be accepted for relaying. N.B.: Sendmail must be restarted after this
>   file is modified.

This and other tips on that page should get you started.  Otherwise, you may want to check into SMTP AUTH if you need to control who can relay email.

Comment: Relay-domains is what you want. Put your companies name in there and disable all other relaying.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a milter for that.  You can do it via sendmail.mc. Add these lines in your sendmail.mc:

```
#Define the smart host
define(`SMART_HOST', `exchange server here')dnl

#Define a class of domains we want to relay to the smart host
C{Exchange} example.com example.org

#Decide whether to delete outgoing email or not
LOCAL_RULE_0
#test the behavior of your system to see if you need the following line
R$* < @ $=w . > $*              $#OK
R$* < @ $={Exchange} . > $*     $#OK
R$*                             $#local $: bit-bucket
```

bit-bucket should be aliased to /dev/null in /etc/mail/aliases:

```
bit-bucket: /dev/null
```

Remember to rebuild sendmail.cf from the sendmail.mv file afterwards and restart sendmail. I do not know how this is done in CentOS. Debian's `sendmailconfg` has made me a little lazy. Also remember that sendmail rules are divided with tabs and not spaces so do not copy-paste. Type by hand and separate the "left" and "right" parts after LOCAL_RULE_0 with tabs.

Comment: This looks good adamo, and looks what i want to do but when i make the changes - regenerate sendmail - then start the daemon i get an error saying :
451 4.0.0 /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 63: fileclass: cannot open 'domain_i_want_mail_sent_to.com': No such file or directory

Is there a file i have to create ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: My mistake! Change F{Exchange} to C{Exchange}. C stands for class definition within the configuration file, while F stands for class definition from an outside file. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks adamo! , however now i get the following in maillog whenever i try to send an email anywhere :

Jan 16 10:33:39 myserver sendmail[3213]: q0FLXd3Z003213: from=myuser, size=49, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201201152133.q0FLXd3Z003213@myserver.my.domain>, relay=myuser@localhost
Jan 16 10:33:39 myserver sendmail[3214]: q0FLXdMU003214: SYSERR(root): buildaddr: no user
Jan 16 10:33:39 myserver sendmail[3213]: q0FLXd3Z003213: to=blah@gmail.com, ctladdr=myuser (4686/100), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30049, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.0.0, stat=Service unavailable

Comment: maybe it has something to do with the bit-bucket alias ? i didnt actually have an /etc/mail/aliases file so i made it and just added 
bit-bucket: /dev/null
is that ok ?

Comment: If it is not in _/etc/mail/aliases_, then it must be in _/etc/aliases_. After editing the aliases file you have to rebuild the aliases database by running _newaliases_

Comment: Im not sure what to do , i put it into /etc/aliases and rebuilt it using newaliases and thats what its looking at but email to anywhere doesnt work.

Comment: somehow i think that local rule syntax R$ blah is blocking everything

Comment: [root@myserver ]# /usr/sbin/sendmail -bt
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>
> 0 me.lastname@mydomain.com
parse              input: me . lastname @ mydomain . com
Parse0             input: me . lastname @ mydomain . com
Parse0           returns: me . lastname @ mydomain . com
ParseLocal         input: me . lastname @ mydomain . com
ParseLocal       returns: $# local $: bit-bucket
parse            returns: $# local $: bit-bucket

Comment: Exactly. That is because you have not put in the C{Exchange} line the domains you are interested in being relayed to your Exchange server. You should _substitute_ example.com and example.org with your domains.

Comment: Yeah i did swap out the example.com and example.org for my domain\s

Comment: could i be because i havent done the proper tabs in the mc ?

Comment: Ive tried going through it line by line (the local rule) and it seems that first line of rules the one with $=w in it - if that line is present all email doesnt work.

Comment: You run the test as 3,0 user@example.com Keep in mind $=w contains the _local_ names, the one the host considers that it is supposed to manage. These should be sent to the Exchange server too. However if removing this line works for you, fine too.

Comment: i have bit more time to work on this problem now - its so close to working but doesnt if i run the ruleset it looks like it works perfectly ie :

Comment: > 3,0 me@mydomain.com
canonify           input: me @ mydomain . com
Canonify2          input: me < @ mydomain . com >
Canonify2        returns: me < @ mydomain . com . >
canonify         returns: me < @ mydomain . com . >
parse              input: me < @ mydomain . com . >
Parse0             input: me < @ mydomain . com . >
Parse0           returns: me < @ mydomain . com . >
ParseLocal         input: me < @ mydomain . com . >
ParseLocal       returns: $# OK
parse            returns: $# OK

Comment: > 3,0 me@gmail.com
canonify           input: me @ gmail . com
Canonify2          input: me < @ gmail . com >
Canonify2        returns: me < @ gmail . com . >
canonify         returns: me < @ gmail . com . >
parse              input: me < @ gmail . com . >
Parse0             input: me < @ gmail . com . >
Parse0           returns: me < @ gmail . com . >
ParseLocal         input: me < @ gmail . com . >
ParseLocal       returns: $# local $: bit-bucket
parse            returns: $# local $: bit-bucket

this output looks like the rules should work fine - but they dont :(

Comment: Question: According to the test it should be working, but the actual run does not, right? Do you see any error message in the logs? Have you restarted the sendmail process?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `relay-domains` is that it permits relaying if the sending system is in that domain.

Using an access database may be the solution. In it put:

To: mycompaniesdomain.com    RELAY

Be sure to have all other relay options off. Sendmail is a complex beast and it may be good to post your mc file.

Comment: mc is too long to post but here are the relevant parts i added from   adamos suggestions :  

`define(`SMART_HOST', `myexchangeserver')  
C{Exchange} mydomain.com  
LOCAL_RULE_0  
R$* < @ $=w . > $*  $#OK  
R$* < @ $={Exchange} . > $* $#OK  
R$*    $#local $: bit-bucket`

Comment: dont worry about the backtick syntax so much - that is correct - i just dont know how format the comment correctly with mini-markdown.
However any help with the actual syntax of what im doing would be much appreciated.